# Paging Native SQL Query in JPA with Hibernate without error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

Thanks for your attention, and sorry for mi English :S

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.X to do some sql native queries. Te code is very simple:

```
private void doIt() throws Exception {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("A very simple native query, which return no entities, but collections of arrays");
        q.setFirstResult(0);
        q.setMaxResults(5);
        Collection<Object> results = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("1"); //Means page 1
        for (Object elem : results) {
            String line = "";
            Object[] row = (Object[]) elem;
            for (Object object : row) {
                if(object==null){
                    object="null";
                }
                line += object +"("+object.getClass()+")"+ ",";
            }
            System.out.println(row.length + " " + line);

        }


        em = getEntityManager();
        q = em.createNativeQuery("The same simple native query, which return no entities, but collections of arrays");
        q.setFirstResult(5);
        q.setMaxResults(5);
        results = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("2"); //Means page 2
       for (Object elem : results) {
            String line = "";
            Object[] row = (Object[]) elem;
            for (Object object : row) {
                if(object==null){
                    object="null";
                }
                line += object +"("+object.getClass()+")"+ ",";
            }
            System.out.println(row.length + " " + line);

        }


        em = getEntityManager();
        q = em.createNativeQuery("The same simple native query, which return no entities, but collections of arrays");
        q.setFirstResult(10);
        q.setMaxResults(5);
        results = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("3"); //Means page 3
        for (Object elem : results) {
            String line = "";
            Object[] row = (Object[]) elem;
            for (Object object : row) {
                if(object==null){
                    object="null";
                }
                line += object +"("+object.getClass()+")"+ ",";
            }
            System.out.println(row.length + " " + line);

        }
    }
```

And my result is this:

```
1 
data1,data2,...,data-n        -->I need this output
data1,data2,...,data-n
data1,data2,...,data-n
data1,data2,...,data-n
data1,data2,...,data-n

2
data1,data2,...,data-n,6      -->OMG! lol
data1,data2,...,data-n,7
data1,data2,...,data-n,8
data1,data2,...,data-n,9
data1,data2,...,data-n,10

3
data1,data2,...,data-n,11
data1,data2,...,data-n,12
data1,data2,...,data-n,13
data1,data2,...,data-n,14
data1,data2,...,data-n,15
```

In short, the output in the first page has n items per row (that's my desired output), but the second and third pages have n+1 items, and the additional item seems to be the number of the row that has been brought.

Someone has the same thing happened? I have searched in the Hibernate's documentation, but I   could not solve this "funny :@" problem.

This code was executed with Toplink, and It doesn' have the problem.

Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way paging is done in Hibernate -- using its `Dialect` implementations. The API for a Dialect is as follows: it takes SQL query to be paged and range information, and produces SQL statement yielding desired rows range.

In case or Oracle Dialect, it can use `ROWNUM` and needs not modify your original query. In case of e.g. DB2 or [SQL Server](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2005Dialect.java#L120) a dialect needs to significantly alter your query (incl. but not limited to adding additional column in the output) to be able to filter desired range for you.

And final thing -- why your first page or result is different. SQL allows (depending on implementation) for constructs like `SELECT TOP n`, so the query for range `[0, n]` and `[m, n]` is often different.